# Replace specific value in dataframe cell R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, merge, r-xlsx

I have a large xlsx file; I am interested in 2 columns: `pat_id` and `param_1`.

The original file looks like this (I replaced values with dots just to type faster):

```
     ......pat_id...........param_1..........
row1 ........123...............0.............
...
...
rowi ........456...............1.............     
...
rowk ........789...............5.............
...
rown ........................................
```

I have a smaller file:

```
pat_id | param_1
123        55
456        33
789        22
```

I want to replace values of `param1` in the original file with the values from a smaller file. Like this:

```
     ......pat_id...........param_1..........
row1 ........123...............55.............
...
...
rowi ........456...............33.............     
...
rowk ........789...............22.............
...
rown ........................................
```

So far:
1) I read two files into dataframes. 
2) I then try to find the row where pat_id == 123, and access the column 'param1' and assign a new value (55).

However, I run into numerous errors.

My last version:

```
data[data == 123, 'param1'] <- small_data[1, 'param1']
```

gives an error:

```
 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, data == curr_pat_id, column, value = "55") : 
  non-existent rows not allowed
```

For some reason, when `data[data == 123, 'param1']` return `NA`...

I tried to explore join/merge alternatives, didn't find a suitable solution.

Basically I just want to say **"where in data pat_id == 123, replace its param_1 value with 55".**

Comment: We can use `match` i.e. `df1$param_1 <- df2$param_1[match(df1$pat_id, df2$pat_id)]`

Comment: @akrun Your code replaces all other values (apart from the three I am interested in) with NA.

Comment: You have a showed a data with `...`.  So, it is not reproducible for others to test.